# Selenium Unable to locate element some times in my program

Tags: python, selenium, field

I am using selenium to input some data into a field. The thing is my program iterates through that field numerous times and some of them it returns the following error. I am not sure what is causing it as it doesn't have a standard pattern of behavior. I have tried differentiating the find_elenemt method with every possible way to find_element but I get the same results. **This is the error:**

> selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such
>   element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"css
>   selector","selector":"[name="username"]"}

And this is the block responsible for the error:

```
#~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~Field Completion~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
email = emailgen()
time.sleep(0.1)
mail = driver.find_element_by_name('email').send_keys(email)
driver.find_element_by_class_name('next-button').click()
time.sleep(0.3)
driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/div[3]/div/div/div[2]/div[1]/form/div[1]/div[2]/select/option[9]").click()
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//select[@name='dob-month']//option[3]").click()
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//select[@name='dob-year']//option[contains(text(),'1993')]").click()
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//button[contains(text(),'next')]").click()
tempuser = email.split('@')[0]
temppass = passwordgen()
time.sleep(0.5)
print('Username = ', tempuser)
print('Password = ', temppass)
combocr()
time.sleep(0.5)
driver.find_element_by_name('username').send_keys(tempuser)
driver.find_element_by_name('password').send_keys(temppass)
driver.find_element_by_name('confirm_password').send_keys(temppass)
driver.find_element_by_css_selector('#root > div > div > div.registration-component.scene-component.mounted > div.scene-content > form > div:nth-child(4) > label > div').click()
driver.find_element_by_css_selector("#root > div > div > div.registration-component.scene-component.mounted > div.scene-content > form > div.next-button > button").click()
print('Acquiring Token..')
time.sleep(1)
```

Answer (score 2):

The element is only being located "sometimes" because it has probably not fully loaded on the page before your attempt to locate it.

I would modify these three lines:

```
email = emailgen()
time.sleep(0.1)
mail = driver.find_element_by_name('email').send_keys(email)
```

To this:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
# add the above imports

email = emailgen()
mail = WebDriverWait(driver, 15).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.NAME, 'email')))
mail.send_keys(email)
```

We are replacing `time.sleep()` with `WebDriverWait` on the email field to ensure it is fully loaded before locating it. `time.sleep()` will wait the same amount of time every time, which is not always enough time for the page to load. 
 `WebDriverWait` performs the exact wait time needed for the element to load, up to 15 seconds. Hopefully this will fix your intermittent errors.

Comment: Thanks, I will try it and reply with the results.

Comment: I have a question, in the parenthesis (driver, 15) is 15 time in seconds? And does it put the variable email inside the element?

Comment: Yes, `15` is 15 seconds. I made a quick modification a few seconds ago to add the `mail.send_keys()` function. In my example, `mail` is just the `WebElement` reference to the email element -- this is why we call `mail.send_keys()` after the element is located.

Comment: Ill need to run around 5-10 tests to check it, thanks though

Comment: @SneakyKiwi Any error messages you encounter, feel free to post them here.

Comment: I am not encountering any errors, I think that fixed it :D

Comment: Actually just encountered an error, I get this now: https://imgur.com/a/JtRX04Q

Comment: @SneakyKiwi The `TimeoutException` indicates that the field took longer than 15 seconds to load -- this can be fixed by changing `15` to `20` or `30`. It also helps to verify there was not an error on the website's end -- when you run into this scenario, if you see the page loaded in the browser already then increasing the wait time should work. If the website has errored and not loaded, then there is not much Selenium can do with that.